# How realistic is Totsuki Culinary Academy?

Tags: shokugeki-no-soma

In the show it's classed as an elite international culinary school, but given the graduation rate (less than 10%) and the idea of study behind it, is it realistic? Is there a real life equivalent?

Comment: Culinary schools are real. See: http://www.thebestschools.org/rankings/best-culinary-schools/ As far as having a graduation rate < 10%, I doubt it. I know med schools limit the graduation rate based on need. Law schools set the entrance requirements based on number of applicants a year (LSAT scores are calculated based on how you rank against your peers). IMO, any school that limits the graduation rate to something that low would go out of business, but that's my WAG.

Comment: Except that they (Tootsuki) didn't impose that limit. That 10% is taken from the average graduation rate from the past years.